# Cordova javascroipt createElement not working in android < 7

Tags: cordova

```js
function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

it not working for android < 7 ???

Comment: isnt javascript working at all? or is it only `createElement()`?

Comment: I would encourage you to write a clear question, with some context, for other users who will eventually find this.

Comment: tks. i fixed, its my fail. use append() for jquery